# Is it possible to prevent Office from saving new documents to OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

When I open Office and select new document — either a new blank document for Word or a new blank presentation for PowerPoint — after I open it automatically saving to OneDrive.

How can I prevent this from saving? I use my OneDrive for other work and I don't want Uninstall OneDrive at all.(I not sign in OneDrive account in office apps, just sign in to office standalone app)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Each Office App (Excel, Word, Powerpoint, ...) has its own save location in options. It is not common across all apps.

I have Office 365, One Drive, and Drop Box. I have my Default Save location set to a folder of mine on drive C:

Using Excel as a sample app, it always saves on my Drive C: (locally) and never One Drive or Drop Box unless I point it that way.

So just set your options correctly and your apps will not save to One Drive.

The above is true for any reasonably modern version of Office.

Here is a screenshot to aid you.

[image]

Outside of Office, also check One Drive settings.

Check OneDrive settings the option for office and turn  it off. The setting is *"Use office applications to sync office files that I open"*

Comment: i have office 2019 and i tested before this solution, but still save in onedrive and one otherthing, i haven't AutoSave OneDrive option in my office apps!

Comment: You might consider repairing Office.  Make sure your documents and mail are backed up for safety. Uninstall Office, restart the computer, install Office after the restart, and then set up saving and test right away. The ability to save in the location of your choice goes back to Office 2007 and probably before.

Comment: i test what you say, when i open a office app, it show popup that say (UPLOAD FAILED You are required to sign in to your upload your changes to this location) because im not sign in my outlook account in word or powerpoint or other office apps, i just sign in my outlook account in office standalone app because it required for opening this app...

Comment: You may need to examine One Drive - All settings for syncing and other cool features which may be over-riding Office. I do have One Drive and set the options for One Drive to keep to itself.

Comment: actually, i read a comment in answer microsoft and i lost address for send you and see it, but its about edit in computer like regedit but not that, that is another app can added with microsoft manager console... you know anyway can disable office from saving to onedrive with change something in regedit or like this?

Comment: See if you can locate that again. I have from Office 95 on Windows 95 here and everything forward to Office 365 on Windows 10 and never had to use the registry to enforce file saving locations. If you can locate the link, I will look.

Comment: im not founded that link, but found another solution please check it https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/159919e0-b58e-49e7-b479-01aa8f314b5c/removing-onedrive-and-sharepoint-save-locations?forum=Office2016ITPro

Comment: This link (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/group-policy/block-onedrive-use-from-office) seems promising. I have not had this issue. I have just now helped a colleague with a customer using Office 2019 and it seems to still have bugs in it. Check for updates

Comment: i opening from original file from install folder and i haven't same problem, and this show the problem from office standalone app, any version of office standalone app that just open app and not doing new blank document or anything from office app, just open the word app and other...

Comment: I still suggest checking your One Drive settings. I have not witnessed or seen myself this issue at any client or business.

Comment: in OneDrive setting i just found this option for office and i set is off: Use office applications to sync office files that i open

Comment: Good. So my answer is good for Office and you now have the One Drive option to fix that problem.  I amended my answer to include this.

Comment: doesn't work, thats not solution

Comment: It might be worth backing up One Drive, remove it (Windows Apps), restart, see if now Office works (should) and then make a decision about One Drive.  I have not seen this (and I have seen lots - more than many people)

Comment: John please see photo that i uploaded...

Comment: I looked at that. Something is wrong with Office or One Drive. I cannot see precisely what is wrong. It says One Drive is not signed in. Ensure your backups. Uninstall Office (Programs and Features); uninstall One Drive (Windows Apps); restart; install just Office and check settings. This should work. Now install One Drive, sign in and check it. This will help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Here are two threads with the "Upload Failed" message. [link1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onedrivefb-mso_win10-mso_o365b/one-drive-upload-failed-you-are-required-to-sign/0790fceb-4d56-489c-81ce-c972af0da04a) and [link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_o365b/upload-failed-you-are-required-to-sign-in-to/b9b9b4a0-4d68-4d9e-b393-82ae3192c805?auth=1&page=2)

Comment: Did the suggestions work for you?  The posts in the links are from a couple of years ago and One Note has changed since.